# When is the first time any variation of the name Misraim is used to refer to Egypt?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt, archaeology, historical-research, ancient-babylon

I asked a question here previously related to this, and I would like to be more specific in this question. There are numerous ancient records such as the Ugaritic tablets, the Assyrian & Babylonian, the Amarna tablets and so forth. So what I would like to find out, is what known record contains the first appearance of this name, in any kind of variation (Misri, Musri, Masri, Msrm etc.)

For instance, the Amarna tablets have correspondences from 1300 B.C., and they contain Misri. So basically the oldest ones we have, would be considered the first. I don't have all the texts or knowledge at hand so it would take quite some time for me to find out this by myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the earliest surviving inscriptions are from the Akkadian period (2350–2150 BCE). "miSru" certainly appears as the word for Egyptian in [A Concise Dictionary of Akkadian](https://archive.org/stream/AConsiceDictionaryAkkadian/CDA_w_corr_djvu.txt)

Comment: Ancient Indians also referred to Egypt as "Misr", but I'll have to search about the earliest reference by them.

Answer (score 3):

The earliest surviving references I've found seem to be from inscriptions dated to the Akkadian period (2350–2150 BCE). "miSru" certainly appears as the word for Egyptian in [A Concise Dictionary of Akkadian](https://archive.org/stream/AConsiceDictionaryAkkadian/CDA_w_corr_djvu.txt), where the word can also mean 'border' or 'frontier'.

Interestingly (or perhaps not!), the CIA seem to have come to the same conclusion about the derivation of the Arabic name for Egypt ("Misr") in their World Factbook entry for [Egypt](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/print_eg.html).